# Is there such a thing as a circuit that outputs 1 if the input is high-impedance, and 0 otherwise?

Tags: digital-logic, cpu, high-impedance

I am trying to design a circuit that outputs a logical 1 if the input is high-impedance, and a 0 otherwise.

Any idea how I might implement this?  I would prefer to use off-the-shelf parts (no programming).

Truth table:

```
I|O
---
X|1
0|0
1|0
```

I was thinking something along the lines of a pull up resistor with an NPN transistor.  Thoughts?

Comment: What is it when it isn't high impedance? A lightning bolt? An open collector pulling to ground? A 5mA current source?

Comment: pull-up resistor.  [The question is vague, though.  What are you testing the impedance of?  And why?]

Comment: I added a truth table.

Comment: @PhilFrost this is in CPU terms, so it would likely be somewhere in the realm of 0V-1.8V to 0V-5V

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 Ah. Makes sense now, with a bit more context to get me thinking about the right kind of electronics.

Comment: @PhilFrost cool :) is it answerable in its current form?

Comment: I'm the guy that came up with this question, and all I really want to know is the name of such a circuit.

Comment: I guess you could call it: "floating input detector".  You could put a resistive voltage divider that pulls to Vcc/2, and with two comparators and an AND gate implement something like: OUTPUT = (lower_than_2/3_Vcc) AND (greater_than_1/3_Vcc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple window comparator will do what you want.

The input is tied to midvoltage by the two 1Mohm resistors.  The references are set at 1/3 and 2/3rds of the supply voltage.  LM339 is open-collector output, so can be OR'ed together to get the desired truth table.

[image]

Google for "window comparator" to get more detail about this circuit.

Please notice that this circuit will not detect a low-impedance connection to half the supply voltage, only low impedances to high or low levels.

Comment: Interesting.  This might be tough to scale, as this is for a microprocessor, but I appreciate the effort, and I'll check this in my sim to make sure it's what I'm looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: LM339 is cheap ($0.33 in *single pieces*) and you get four comparators (two copies of this circuit) per chip.

Comment: Does your microcontroller have ADC inputs?  You can do the same trick in software, just the 1M+1M midpoint supply is all the hardware you need.  If your micro has switchable pull-up / pull-down resistors, you could use those in succession and avoid any extra components.

Comment: the circuit is designed to be part of a CPU pipeline, so I'm not sure that will work.  I am going to explore this, though.

Comment: Also, the 10k+10k+10k divider chain can be shared among any number of comparator circuits.